# How to pay taxes on YouTube if I'm a dependent?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I'm a citizen living in the US (Texas, dunno if it matters) and I am a dependent according to my parents. I am a light YouTuber and have made almost nothing, literally $0.03. When do I pay taxes, and how? Is there a way to do it on a computer or my phone?
**Edit:** I don't make any other income

Comment: Do you have any other income besides the YouTube income?

Comment: @BenMiller Not me personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Form 1040 (U.S. tax return form) Instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi/index.html) has a section called ["Do You Have To File?"](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi/ar01.html#d0e413).  Below a certain income, you are not required to file a tax return and pay any tax.  This amount of income at which you are required to file depends on several things, including your dependency status (you are a dependent of your parents), your marital status, and other factors.  The instructions have charts that show what these numbers are.  You would fall under [Chart B](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi/ar01.html#en_US_2015_publink24811vd0e1072).

Assuming that you are under age 65, unmarried, and not blind, you only have to file when you reach the following conditions:

> Your unearned income was over $1,050.
>
> Your earned income was over $6,300.
>
> Your gross income was more than the larger of—
>
> > $1,050, or
> >
> > Your earned income (up to $5,950) plus $350.

(Note: Income from YouTube would count as "earned income" for the purposes above.)

However, if you are producing your own videos and receiving revenue from them, you are technically self-employed.  This means that the conditions from [Chart C](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi/ar01.html#en_US_2015_publink24811vd0e1436) also apply, which state:

> You must file a return if any of the five conditions below apply for 2015.
>
> > 3. You had net earnings from self-employment of at least $400.

As a self-employed person, you can deduct business expenses (expenses that you incur in producing your product, which is this case is your videos).  Once your revenue minus your expenses reach $400, you will need to file an income tax return.

Comment: Asking - if one gets a $600 1099 from Google, won't our uncle be expecting to see that on a tax return? Shouldn't he still file even if there's over $200 in expenses?

Comment: This was so helpful!

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer [Good question.](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/67157/10997)