# Does receiving a 1099-MISC require one to file a tax return even if he normally would not be required to file?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099-misc

Suppose a person is self-employed and earning below the minimum income at which he is required to file.  According to the Form 1040 Instructions [Chart C](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi/ar01.html#en_US_2015_publink24811vd0e1436), one of these requirements is:

> You must file a return if any of the five conditions below apply for 2015.
>
> > 3. You had net earnings from self-employment of at least $400.

The term "net earnings" implies that this would be profit from self-employment after business expenses are deducted.

Now, let's suppose that this person has received a 1099-MISC for some amount greater than $400, but with business expenses, he has "net earnings" for the year less than $400.

Does he need to file a tax return in this situation?  Will the IRS be concerned that he did not file even if he received a 1099?

---

This hypothetical question was inspired by [How to pay taxes on YouTube if I'm a dependent?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/67147/10997) and [JoeTaxpayer's comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/67147/how-to-pay-taxes-on-youtube-if-im-a-dependent#comment105457_67149).

Answer (score 5):

> Does he need to file a tax return in this situation? Will the IRS be concerned that he did not file even if he received a 1099?

No.

However, if you don't file the IRS may come back asking why, or "make up" a return for you assuming that the whole amount on the 1099-MISC is your net earnings.

So in the end, I suspect you'll end up filing even though you don't have to, just to prove that you don't have to. Bottom line - if you have 1099 income (or any other income reported to the IRS that brings you over the filing threshold), file a return.